# Plotting 0-360 degrees

Tags: graphing-functions

I have some direction (bearing from north) data in degrees.  Some of this data jumps between 1-360 degrees when plotted as a line graph, which is not easy to read, as the variation is actually only 1 degree.  What is the best way to graph such data (preferably using Excel)?

Unfortunately, applying a fixed value to all values is not an option as the full range of 0-360 degrees is covered in the dataset.

Comment: Have you looked into polar coordinates? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: I have actually plotted with polar coords already.  I should add that ideally, I'd like to plot bearing over time.

Comment: If you're not opposed to using them, then you could do bearing as the angle and time as the distance from the centre. Though this assumes your times are all non-negative. If some are negative you could offset them so that the origin is at your smallest time.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is polar graph $\theta=f(r)$, where $\theta$ is your angle data and $r$ increases with time. I don't know how to plot such graphs in Excel directly, so I converted into $XY$ coordinates using $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$, then used scatterplot with connecting lines. I think the evolution of angle over time is clear.

[image: polar plot]

I removed the distracting Cartesian grid and added a red point  to mark the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to assume the change between points is less than $\pm 180^\circ$ and add or subtract multiples of $360^\circ$ to each point to make that true.  It means your plotted values may go outside the range $0-360$, but the variation from point to point will be represented correctly.  You could give that a try.